# draft-js convertToRaw method is not working

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, draftjs

I use [draft-js-plugins](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/). I used the emoji and the mention plugins together in my Editor. When I am using ,

`convertToRaw(contentState)`

to save my content data into the db, it shows an error message.

> immutable.js:1421 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined

But this error only comes when I have used mention in my content. it works fine with plain text and emojis contents. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with this for a several time I found the reason. Here I am trying to save an immutable content into the DB. And trying to pass that data to the back-end via an Ajax call.

When we post data via an ajax call, we have to use `JSON.stringify` and `application/json; charset=utf-8` as follows.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/calendar/event/add',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }).done(function (data, text) {
        if(data.status.code == 200){
            console.log("Success");
        }
    }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you using [draft-js plugins editor](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins)? It works fine for me, although I got confused between `editorState` and `contentState` in the beginning. These kind of ***errors pop up*** when I try to do `convertToRaw(editorState)` make sure you are doing something like this:

```
_onChange (editorState) {
  this.setState({
    editorState,
  });
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  console.log(convertToRaw(contentState));
}
```

Comment: Please share me, which versions you are using. Currently they have publish a beta of next version. I am using those beta versions of " draft-js plugins editor", "emoji plugin" and the "mentions plugin"

Comment: My `package.json` says `"draft-js-plugins-editor": "^2.0.0-beta1"`

Comment: Please map others also,

    "draft-js-emoji-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta1",
    "draft-js-mention-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta1",
    "draft-js-plugins-editor": "^2.0.0-beta1",

Comment: We are already on 2.0.0-beta6. I recommend you to upgrade all of them to this version and try again.

Comment: Hi @NikGraf . Currently I have upgrade the plugins to "2.0.0-beta6" versions. But the issue is still exists. I have created a sample code in the following repo. Please visit.
 
https://github.com/erangakapukotuwa/draft-js-sample

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa mine should be the accepted answer and not your own, because your answer has nothing to do with draftjs and also doesn't event explain what the problem was in the first place. This is irrelevant.